# Get remote IP adress not working on node

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get the remote IP address from an incoming connection using express. Already tried the common solutions found in the web:

1. req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] / result: always undefined
2. req.socket.remoteAddress / result: always getting the Gateway IP (IE: 192.168.1.1) instead of the external address.

Any clues?

Comment: Your gateway should not rewrite the address of external connections to its own address. How are you establishing the incoming connection for your tests?

Comment: Are you running some kind of reverse proxy in front of your express app? Like nginx, lighttpd or varnish?

Comment: As Linus implied, that example assumes you've got a reverse proxy in front of node. Have you inspected the req.headers array to see if the origin IP is in there in its original form? I believe it should be.

Comment: I'm testing this at home, where I have a dd-wrt router and several computers. I've tried this running the nodejs server in Windows / OS X and Linux (3 flavors). Node isn't behind anything. The X-Forwarded-For returns undefined, even when using the browser at the local host (used chrome, safari and firefox) so I guess the test code in the response "would" work because in that case it would always fallback over the req.socket.remoteAddress, which gives me 192.168.1.1 even on native Ubuntu. Any way, the only thing I want is the external address, which I CAN obtain using PHP with the same PC

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this by running the app in a VM on your own machine? If so, you're getting the right answer.  The X-Forwarded-For is empty, since there's no proxy, and you're seeing the virtual interface on the host machine which the VM uses to route out from.  That's the IP from which the request comes.

Answer (score -3):

Here's some code i used at http://th.issh.it/ip

Maybe it's case sensitive?

```
exports.iptoy = function(req,res) {
    var clientip = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    var xffip  = req.header('X-Forwarded-For');
    var ip = xffip ? xffip : clientip;
    if(req.params.format == 'json')
        res.send({client:clientip,xforwardedfor:xffip});
    else
        res.send(ip+"\n");
}
```

Comment: Actually looks like req.header is a function, not an array

Comment: `req.header` is a function, `req.headers` is an object.

Comment: Is this example made to be used with the Express framework? I still get undefined with X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Yes, you can try it at the URL above... There's something wrong with the reverse proxy in front of your app - stop it and try `nc -l localhost 3000` from the command line, and you'll see what headers it's actually passing.